# Excel - change number comma format to xxxx,xxx (only 1 comma)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

If I have:

1813412

I want to format the comma placement to ONLY the first thousands place, like this:

1813,412

I do NOT want this: 1,813,412. I just want the first single comma.

I looked at Format cells > Number > Custom, but none of the given options accomplish this. I'm also not sure how to write the custom code. Any help?

Comment: Are all the numbers greater than or equal to 1,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trail and error, found the solution:

**#"",##0**

Comment: Note that the numbers will look strange if they are less than 1,000. For example, 12 will appear as ",012".